# FastAPI decorators on endpoint

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm trying to create role-based access control on endpoint and since fastAPI has this build-in Depends method with possibility to cache result I'm trying to create something like this

```
@router.get('/')
#decorator 
@roles_decorator("admin")
async def get_items(user_id: str = Depends(get_current_user)):

return await get_all_items()
```

**get_current_user method** will need to receive roles from decorator (in this case admin) and from authorization service receive user_id if role matches provided role. So my question is, can we pass the role from decorator to method in Depends, or is there any chance that we can do this role-based access control with predefined roles for every endpoint?

```
def get_current_user(role):
    #connect to auth_serivce and do other logic
    return user_id
```

Comment: i dont quite follow what your asking ... to get the roles available to a user you need to get_current_user first ... so how could you pass roles into it?

Comment: I asked a similar question. Hope to get some answers :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74652763/decorator-with-arguments-for-fastapi-endpoint

Comment: @JoranBeasley so i need to pass role to get_current_user which will send role to authorization service decode jwt token and see if roles are matching, is this maybe better explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to mix dependencies and decorators (which won't do anything good), you can instead use a dynamically configured dependency:

```py
async def get_current_user_with_role(role):
    async def get_user_and_validate(user=Depends(get_current_user)):
        if not user.has_role(role):
            raise 403

        return user.id

    return get_user_and_validate
```

This will bind the `role` value you give to the dependency when it gets created:

```
@router.get('/')
async def get_items(user_id: str = Depends(get_current_user_with_role("admin"))):
    pass
```

Comment: With this you cannot pass  param "admin" also so I think this is not game changer, and also I don't receive user object with role, I'm getting id of user but to get that ID I need to send role from endpoint to see if role which I send from endpoint are same as role from JWT token decrypted on auth service

Comment: You pass `"admin"` when you add the dependency. What you receive back depends on what you return from the `get_user_and_validate` function - you defined this as being a `str` in your original post, together with only having a `user_id` and not a user object. If you want t user object, return the user object from `get_current_user_with_role` instead when the role matches.

Comment: Oh okay I think I got this thanks, there is only one thing to try to implement with decorator to pass to that method

Comment: _Generally_ FastAPI doesn't really use decorators for things like that, but instead use the dependency resolution framework.

Comment: so this is bad idea to use decorator and depends?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to use a decorator when it can be solved with a dependency alone.

Comment: just for readability reasons to be on top of the route

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Python and FastAPI but passing params to a dependency wasn't working too well for me, and it started causing the params to appear in Swagger which wasn't what I wanted.

My endpoints require API keys for authentication, so I check who the API key belongs to and if they have the required permissions to access the endpoint.

Coming from other frameworks where I'd use a decorator for this kind of thing, I ended up implementing it this way in my FastAPI project:

Here's the decorator:

```py
def has_permission(permission: str):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            api_key = kwargs.get("api_key_header")
            user_service = kwargs.get("user_service")

            user = user_service.get_by_api_key(api_key)

            if permission not in user.permissions
                raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="User doesn\'t have required permissions")

            return await func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

And this is how I use it on my route:

```py
@router.get("/", summary="Retrieve all users.", response_model=List[UserResponse])
@has_permission("users.get")
async def get_all_users(
    api_key_header: str = Security(api_key_header), user_service: UserService = Depends(UserService)
):
    """
    Retrieve all users.
    """
    return user_service.get_all_users()
```

Comment: This works well and is what I used in my project, however it raises another issue. If params or a body is required by the endpoint, this will be checked before any auth checks. e.g. a Pydantic schema for a body to that endpoint will raise exceptions until the body is sent correctly, only then will it check the auth. Not really something you want to have on protected endpoints. Better to have auth first then validation. I couldn't figure a way around that.

Comment: @MarkBarrett Applying the auth check at the router level might be more appropriate if looking to check auth before params/body hits the endpoint.

Comment: yea. I managed to make it work by modifying the Depend @MatsLindh mentioned above. Validates the auth first.