# Decorator WITH arguments for FastAPI endpoint

Tags: python, fastapi, python-decorators

I'm having this decorator:

```
def security(required_roles):
    def decorator(function):
        async def wrapper():
            print("ROLES", required_roles)
            return function
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

and this endpoint, I want to decorate:

```
@app.get(
    "/me", summary="Get details of currently logged in user", response_model=SystemUser
)
@security(required_roles=["role1", "role2"])
async def get_me(user: SystemUser = Depends(get_current_user)):
    return user
```

But when I call it I get this:

```
File "/home/niels/PycharmProjects/fastApiProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 139, in serialize_response
    raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_)
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for SystemUser
response
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

Can anybody tell me why and how I could rewrite the decorator. If I place the decorator ***before*** `@app.get(...)` it does not get executed, also not sure why. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got my decorator working by doing the following:

Decorator:

```py
def has_permission(permission: str):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            api_key = kwargs.get("api_key_header")
            user_service = kwargs.get("user_service")

            user = user_service.get_by_api_key(api_key)

            if permission not in user.permissions
                raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="User doesn\'t have required permissions")

            return await func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

Route:

```py
@router.get("/", summary="Retrieve all users.", response_model=List[UserResponse])
@has_permission("users.get")
async def get_all_users(
    api_key_header: str = Security(api_key_header), user_service: UserService = Depends(UserService)
):
    """
    Retrieve all users.
    """
    return user_service.get_all_users()
```

Note how I access the route params by doing `kwargs.get()`.

Answer (score -1):

You should pass the wrapper arguments to the wrapped function and `await` it:

```
def security(required_roles):
    def decorator(function):
        async def wrapper(user):
            print("ROLES", required_roles)
            return await function(user)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Comment: Then I get: 
`{"detail": [{"loc": ["query", "args"], "msg": "field required", "type": "value_error.missing" }, {
"loc": ["query", "kwargs"], "msg": "field required", "type": "value_error.missing"}]}`

Comment: And if I move the `*args, **kwargs` to `decorator(...)` I get: `{"dependency": {},use_cache": true}` So apparently then the Depends does not get executed for some reason. When I print it, I just see `Depends(get_current_user)`

Comment: FastAPI inspects the argument names of the function as the parameter names for the GET query, so the wrapper needs to have the same arguments as the wrapped function. Updated my answer accordingly then.